# Android array check for a value

Tags: android, arrays

My Problem is that I have 8 EditText where you can type different numbers and I write them into an ArrayList.

But those EditeText which are empty should not be written into the ArrayList because I don't need in my application.

I.e. I only want those which have a number in it.

Comment: why is your title in german?

Comment: What do you want to store in the arraylist? the values of the textedits or a reference to those textedits?

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayList<EditText> textArr = new ArrayList(8);
textArr.add(myNumberOneEditText);...
```

when you need to gather data to the int `ArrayList:

```
int i = 0;
for (EditText editText : textArr){
    if(editText.getText() != null && editText.getText().length > 0){
        yourDataArr.add(i, editText.getText().toString());
    }
    i++;
}
```

if your `dataArr` is of Integer type your should convert the String to int...also optimize the loop and remove the excessive call to `getText()` (add a param)

Comment: Thanks for that answer but the problem is that those which are epmty souldn't be write into the array.

Comment: as you can see first i'm checking if the editText is empty (`getText != null` and `getText.length > 0`). only if they do not contain data i'm adding them to the arr at the right location